# Insert value in input box by clicking a hyperlink

Tags: javascript, input

A table column displays student id numbers as follows:- (PHP code)

```
echo "<td><b><a href = '#'><h1>".$res['studid']."</h1></a></b></td>";
```

Below the table there is an input box to enter student id

I want to add the value of $res variable into the input box when the user clicks the above link.

That value will be later used to search the result of that particular student

How to achieve this with Javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var studentLinks=document.querySelectorAll('td>b>a>h1');
for(var i=0;i<studentLinks.length;i++){
  studentLinks[i].parentNode.addEventListener('click',function(){
    document.getElementById('yourInputField').value=this.children[0].innerHTML;
  });
}
```

Non-jQuery way of applying this functionality to all elements.

By the way, the `a` element is then non-essential, so it could as well be removed and `td>b>h1` be written as the selector instead.

Anyways, the above JavaScript is applied to all links. You can also put an `e` inside the brackets after `function` and at the top of the function block add `e.preventDefault();` to make absolutely sure that the page doesn’t redirect anywhere.

Comment: He want to click on the link not in the h1, so remove the h1.

Comment: Alright, then I’ll edit my answer to my first approach… I thought it would be easier without.

Comment: @ShubharajBuwa …which is kind of impressive because I didn’t test any of that prior to answering…

Comment: @Xufox - Your code is working fine.  But instead of adding the value of the  $res variable to input box is it possible to directly display search results when a user clicks the hyperlink  (his/her id number) - i.e. Want to pass on the variable to the php file which displays the result through the link.

Comment: @ShubharajBuwa Yes, I think so, but it depends on how your server request looks like. Do you have a send button? You could try to use the code from that one in the event listener. If it’s largely written in PHP: I’m no expert in PHP, especially not in mixing PHP and JavaScript…

Comment: @Xufox Thank you very much for all your efforts, I will try what you have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

```js
  var link = document.getElementById('studentId');
  var input = document.getElementById('search');
  link.addEventListener('click', function() {
    input.value = this.innerText;
  });
```

```html
<td><b><a href='#' id="studentId"><h1>Some text</h1></a></b>
</td>
<input type="text" id="search">
```

Answer (score 0):

Well a Jquery way...

```
$("#table a").click(function(){
   $("#input").val($(this).find('h1').text());
 });
```